# Windows Forms templated data

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application that wraps Lua to enable interactivity with geometric shapes and their properties and I am about to finish but... in the main window, I have a flowlayout panel that should show the properties for said shape, as how Lua dictates.

Here comes problem/question as I don't think clearing the panel and re-adding the controls that represent each property, each time I have to update the properties is a good idea nor the most effective solution, is there something I can do to enhance this?

Comment: If you could give a little more info, we might be able to help you more effectively. You should be able to update an individual control within the flowlayout panel without re-populating the whole thing.

Comment: More info? Please tell me what do you need from me? Also: Do the Label's text setters force a repaint? - That's another way to put the question.

Comment: No, this will suck mud badly, not counting the code to keep track of the controls.  Use ListView or DataGridView or PropertyGrid.